# Design university schedule system

Tags: database-design, application-design

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask for tips and improvements in a database design but I don't know about another one.

I want to design a simple University system. Below I'll have included a schema that I've comed up with.

[image: schema]

The idea is that each `group` will have multiple `semesters`. Number of them will be equal to `study_programs.years_of_study * 2`.

I want to store each semester for each group because of that fact that disciplines may appear or disappear over time. I'll be handling this change with creation/deletion of `lectures`. The main idea is that old semesters won't be touched - this way I can retrieve them later.

---

Is this a good way of keeping history intact? Maybe you can propose another methods? I'll happily listen to all of them. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the purpose of `groups` and `study_programs`? Also, it is wise, for historic purposes, to have strong entities have a validity rule (a valid boolean field, or a validity period, or an expired field, etc) rather than delete them. That way one can query historic information as well as enable for current views filtering out all expired/non-current entities.

Comment: Of course. The fact is that I've left out a lot of entities that don't influence the problem about history integrity of schedules. As it turns out I have more business data to deal with, `departments`, a lot of `specialities` and different `study_programs` for them. I wanted to have an image as clear as possible.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting to add `deleted_at` column to entities I want to keep around for archiving.